# Standardized format for contributing street closure data to navigation apps

Tags: google-maps, geojson, spatial-database, transportation, navigation

I am wanting to put together an application that will digest georeferenced road closure data. I am wondering if any such format currently exists for notifying google maps or other navigation applications so that I am not recreating the wheel.

If there is not a format that is currently used would some form of GeoJSON be the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is jurisdiction dependent in North America as every State, Provincial, and/or Federal Agency has their own set of ways on how they communicate this sort of thing. There are a few '511' service providers out there and some of them are [opensource](http://www.open511.org/). I would check with  TRB for standard docs as well as the jurisdictions you're looking to deploy this too.

In addition to all of this, each jurisdiction, road authority, or EMO distributes information slightly different than the other and some don't give out information at all.

Can you provide more details on what you're trying to solve? are you trying to build an app that syncs all `511` alerts together?

Comment: The Open511 was exactly what I was looking for. I just wanted to put together documentation for standards for road closures in a machine readable format. The second part of this idea is to allow transit providers  to "subscribe" to the feed to see if there is any conflicts and potentially send messages to customers who "subscribe" to stops.